# Grep get value from key

Tags: grep, text-processing

I have a Linux command which outputs `Category: value`
I want to extract just the value(using grep ig)
I already tried `|grep -vo "value"` but it doesn't even print the line.
An example would be:
Given the command:

```
Category1: 33
Category2: 45
Category3: 234
```

I would like to only get `234` if I input "Category3: ", `33` if I input "Category1: " and so on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
echo 'Category1: 33
Category2: 45
Category3: 234' | awk '/^Category/{print $2}'
33
45
234
```

If the first word on the line starts with `Category` (ignoring numbers and colons) print the second word.

Comment: Thanks, but could you delete the ">" from your post? It worked without it

Comment: Well ... that's just some sample data I echo; you said a program generated your output. @Dioswison

Comment: Yeah, i copied your echo and it didn't work, i had to remove the ">" characters to make it work

Comment: Those angle brackets happened because I copy & pasted your sample data into my shell. I type the `echo '`, then pasted, then type`'` ... the line-wrapping with `>` was the shell's doing which I didn't pull out when copy & pasting back ;) @Dioswison

Answer (score 0):

You can get the `"value"` by using this code:

```
echo "Category: value" |grep -o "value"
```

Note: The grep command `-o` will only display the matched part of lines. Also, `echo` will just simply display a line of text.

Comment: Forgot to say, "value" is a variable, so can't search for a specific keyword. In this case it is am output from a command